# TSR in assembly save in memory

Tags: assembly, dos, terminate

I have problem with TSR, trying to save in memory and when start "program" to keep writing something else, and in behind to keep working (stopwatch).

This is the code:

```asm
cli
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
mov bx, [es:1Ch*4]
mov [old_int_off], bx
mov bx, [es:1Ch*4+2]
mov [old_int_seg], bx

mov dx, timer
mov [es:1Ch*4], dx
mov ax, cs
mov [es:1Ch*4+2], ax
push ds
pop gs
sti

mov ax,3100h
mov dx,500
int 21h
```

When I start program, I can writing something else. When I press<kbd>F1</kbd> to start stopwatch, nothing happened.

But without this:

```asm
mov ax, 3100h
mov dx, 500
int 21h
```

F1 work, but i can't writing.

Comment: What actually does **timer** do? It is invoked every 55ms and the only known information at this moment is CS:IP. Your manipulation with GS looks suspisious to me. Timer should load DS from CS if it is used to write to memory at data segment. And it should terminate with far jump to [old_int_seg:old_int_ofs].

Comment: Replace "[old_int_seg]" by "cs:[old_int_seg]" to save and load bx effectively in the segment of your program.